# Jar-библиотека динамическая или статическая?

Tags: jar, java, библиотеки

Какие еще библилотеки бывают в Java?
Перешел на Java с C++ и сразу возникли такие вопросы

Answer (score 2):

Classloader загружает классы по мере необходимости. Так что как бы динамическая. Других нет.

Comment: Ну почему же нет других - есть еще нативные статические библиотеки загружаемые через `System.loadLibrary()`

Comment: JNI в моей модели мира уже не совсем java-библиотеки ) И это же тоже динамические библиотеки, а не статические.